# What are Octaves and Sub levels in KAZE and AKAZE?

Tags: opencv, feature-detection, keypoint, ransac

I am having a hard time trying to understand the Octaves and Sub-levels in the Non-Linear Scale space (KAZE and AKAZE). For the SIFT- Octaves is a collection of same sized images and sub-level is number of gaussian blurred images to be generated in the octave. How can this be explained in KAZE and AKAZE?
I want to tune the parameters and so need to understand this properly.

Answer (score 0):

The octaves are the number of scale levels. 4 octaves means scales of 1, 1/2, 1/4, 1/8.

The octave layers are the number of diffusion layers per octave. Diffusion is the change in luminance of an image that is farther away. It can be (and it is) aproximated by some gaussian blur.

See the original AKAZE paper for more details:
http://www.robesafe.com/personal/pablo.alcantarilla/papers/Alcantarilla13bmvc.pdf

See figure 2 in this paper, for a representation of the image pyramid:
http://tulipp.eu/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/2017_TUD_HEART_kalms.pdf